# How to get UIAlertAction (UIAlertController) response from block handler?

Tags: objective-c, ios8.1, uialertcontroller

I have this code where I want to display a message with a YES or NO response using UIAlertAction;  this is my code:

```
-(void) displayAlert: (NSString *)alertTitle andMessage: (NSString *)alertMessage andViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController andTag:(int)tag {

//  create controller
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                                      message:alertMessage
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

//  add buttons
if(tag == 0)  {  //  ok/cancel response
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {

                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {

                               }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];
}
else if(tag == 1)  {  //  yes/no response
    UIAlertAction *noAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"No action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {

                               }];

    UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"Yes action")
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                {

                                }];

    [alertController addAction:noAction];
    [alertController addAction:yesAction];
}


//  display controller  
[viewController presentViewController: alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

My problem is that the block does not allow a return (according to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:)).  So how  do I return the response to the calling method? (it's not inline, it's in a class of common methods because it's used often).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a return value from block. Instead you can do the following:

- Add completion block parameter to your `displayAlert` method. And include into this block definition an argument that would indicate button pressed (yes/no or whatever)
- Call this completion block from both block handlers that you already have and pass proper value into it.

This way your application code can define one completion block that will be executed in both cases (when user tapped Yes or No) and you can handle it there.

Comment: Can you please add example that shows how to pass handler as parameter?

Comment: @Satyam: In the original question there is a code `UIAlertAction actionWithTitle` that basically does same thing.

Comment: @sha, I understood how UIAlertAction closure is passed as parameter. But how to call it on Yes/No button press event?

Comment: @Satyam: `if (self.confirmationCompletionBlock) {
        self.confirmationCompletionBlock(confirmed);
    }`